# Jquery/PHP: Result of jQuery function into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a little question about Java and PHP. I didn't find what i was looking for in this forum so i think its better to ask.

I have a Javascript function (see below) and not made myself! that automatically counts and makes a total price when the customer is changing multi choice buttons.

```
function fncCheck() {
                   var subtotaal = 0;
                   var combikorting = 0;
                   var totaal = 0;
                   var toeslagcontant = 0;
                   var totaaltebetalen = 0;

                   if (document.getElementById("ek").checked == true && document.getElementById("epc").checked == false) {
                        subtotaal = subtotaal + 115;
                        toeslagcontant = 5;
                        document.getElementById("elektrischekeuring").style.display = "block";
                   } else {
                       document.getElementById("elektrischekeuring").style.display = "none";
                   }

                   if (document.getElementById("ek").checked == true && document.getElementById("epc").checked == true) {
                        subtotaal = subtotaal + 125;
                        toeslagcontant = 5;
                        document.getElementById("elektrischekeuring").style.display = "block";
                   } else {
                       document.getElementById("elektrischekeuring").style.display = "none";
                   }

                   if (document.getElementById("epc").checked == true) {
                        if (document.getElementById("studio").checked == true) {
                            subtotaal = subtotaal + 115;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("appartement").checked == true) {
                            subtotaal = subtotaal + 140;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("rijwoning").checked == true) {
                            subtotaal = subtotaal + 165;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("halfopenwoning").checked == true) {
                            subtotaal = subtotaal + 165;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("vrijstaandewoning").checked == true) {
                            subtotaal = subtotaal + 170;
                        }
                        toeslagcontant = 5;
                   }

                   if (document.getElementById("gk").checked == true) {
                        subtotaal = subtotaal + 130;
                        toeslagcontant = 5;
                   }

                   if (document.getElementById("ek").checked == true && document.getElementById("epc").checked == true) {
                        if (document.getElementById("studio").checked == true) {
                            combikorting = 0;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("appartement").checked == true) {
                            combikorting = 10;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("rijwoning").checked == true) {
                            combikorting = 15;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("halfopenwoning").checked == true) {
                            combikorting = 15;
                        } else if (document.getElementById("vrijstaandewoning").checked == true) {
                            combikorting = 10;
                        }
                    }

                   totaal = subtotaal - combikorting


                   document.getElementById("totaal").innerHTML = totaal + " EUR";

                   if (document.getElementById("terplaatse").checked == true) {
                       totaaltebetalen = totaal + toeslagcontant;
                   } else {
                       totaaltebetalen = totaal;
                   }

                   document.getElementById("totaaltebetalen").innerHTML = totaaltebetalen + " EUR";     
               } 

HTML: 

<h2>Total à payer:</h2><br />
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:270px;">
                        <tr style="height:25px">
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><strong class="pricetext"><div id="totaaltebetalen">0 EUR</div></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

i would like to insert the "totaaltebetalen" (price) into my database. How can i store this into a variable so that i can do an "INSERT INTO" with all my other variables on the same time.

Comment: That's javaSCRIPT, not Java.

Comment: Javascript runs client-side while PHP is server-side, so your JS should make a request to a PHP script on the server with all the data you want to insert, and the PHP script should insert that data into the database.

Comment: you can use Ajax or save the totaaltebetalen value in a hidden field or textbox on your form and send it to server

Comment: Hi Nouphal, thanks for the tip do you have an example how to put it into an textbox/Hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the total on the server side, using your database's prices, rather than anything submitted by the user, otherwise a malicious client could submit their own total and your server would accept it. `(e.g. price=-10000.00)`,
Unless you're actually asking the user for the price, e.g. How much would you like to sell your item for....

The form that gets submitted will have an "action" associated with it (the url that will process the data submitted on the form)

The form's fields will be available to php via the `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` variables.
You can then calculate the price on the server side, using the form's input field values.

e.g. `$_POST['apartmentID']`

#### EDIT / Additional

So if your input names are ek, gpc and gk, you can do something along the lines of the following in PHP:

```
$value = 0;
$discount = 0;
if (!empty($_REQUEST['ek'])){ //this will only be set if the item was ticked/checked
    $value = 100;
    $ek_chk = true;
}
if (!empty($_REQUEST['epc'])){
    $value += 150; // not to sure here if you want to add to or replace value 
    if ($ek_chk) $discount = 0.2;
}
if (!empty ($_REQUEST['gpc'])){
    $value += 200;
}
$total = $value * (1-$discount);
....
//save total to database;
....
```

Comment: That was the first thing i thought to do, but it is necessary for my customer that you see the price changing when you click the value's. That is the reason why i use this Javascript code...

Comment: That's true, but you should still do the final calculation on your server. The user can see the same as what the server will calculate when the form is submitted. But if you just accept the value from the user's computer in your database, then you are asking for trouble as the user could possibly change the calculation by changing the javascript. i.e. you need to do both

Comment: Oh, now i understand. So i could keep the javascript just for showing to the customer but when they submit i could do a switch in PHP to calculate the price? Thank you very much for the explanation! I will give it a try!

Comment: Is there someone who could give me an example of a calculation in PHP. For example: You have three check-boxes (ek,epc,gk) all three are carying a value 1 in the HTML (i.e. : <input type="checkbox" name="ek" value="1" id="ek"/><label for="ek">test1</label>). price when "ek" is checked = 100, price when "epc" is checked: 150, price when "gk" is checked = 200. When "ek" and "epc" are both checked you have a discount of 20. much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for all the tips (special thanks to Loopo), 
this is how i have done it:

i i.e. have 3 radio buttons & 3 checkbox buttons :

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="example" value="one" id="one" checked /><label for="studio">One</label>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="two" id="two" /><label for="two">Two</label>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="three" id="three" /><label for="three">Three</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="ek" value="1" id="ek" /><label for="ek">ek</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="epc" value="1" id="epc" "/><label for="epc">epc</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="gk" value="1" id="gk" "/><label for="gk">gk</label>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $var = $_POST['example'];

        $value = 0;
    $discount = 0;

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['ek'])){
        $value = 115;
    }

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['ek']) && ($_REQUEST['epc'])){
        $value = 125;
    }


    if (!empty($_REQUEST['epc']) && ($building === 'one')){  
            $value += 115; 
        }
    elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['epc']) && ($building === 'two')){ 
            $value += 165;
            $discount = 10;
        }
    elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['epc']) && ($building === 'three')){
            $value += 170;
            $discount = 10;
        }

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['gk'])){
            $value += 130;
        } 

        $total = $value - $discount;
}
```

It is possible this is a long version,... But maybe it can help some people in the future!